# Spring Boot 2 with pgBouncer pooling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a PostgreSQL 11 server with pgBouncer pooling set up and enabled.

I'd like to use its pooling mechanism rather than default Hikari and Tomcat pooling that come with the Spring Boot's `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. I've disabled `HikariCP` and `tomcat-jdbc` from the project however, I'm not sure what I'd need to set up further in order to launch the Spring app successfully.

I guess my question is how to set up a Spring application so that it doesn't use any pooling mechanism to communicate with the db as it will be handled by `pgBouncer` on the db side?

I have looked at a variety of questions and answers to somewhat similar questions which led to me disabling `HikariCP` to start with. However, I was unable to find a concise tutorial/example of how I could make this work in my case scenario.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: So disapibting. All answers are yalking about disabling Hikari, bur nobody told a rhing about prepared statements and transactions. I guess all of present were using pgBouncer in srssion node, not transaction mode. Which have no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to define a `DataSource`, so I created a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String uri;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(DriverManager.getDriver(uri));
        dataSource.setUrl(uri);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem, and after looking at the spring source codes I found  an easier way that does not require any code or pom changes.

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    type: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

This datasource will simply replace hikari and create a new connection every time instead of pooling.

Answer (score 2):

Have to exclude it from dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```